# Installing k9s on Ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes

I am using snap install k9s to install k9s on ubuntu. However, that installs a much older version 0.5.1 whereas the latest version is 0.27.4. Can Someone please help me in how to install the latest version or how to update this older version to latest. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are perhaps on the edge channel. Change to the stable channel.

```
$ snap info k9s
[...]
channels:
  latest/stable:    v0.27.4 2023-06-10 (155) 19MB -
  latest/candidate: ↑                             
  latest/beta:      ↑                             
  latest/edge:      0.5.1   2019-04-19  (99)  9MB devmode
```

If you DON'T have the k9s snap installed, then
`snap install k9s --channel=latest/stable`

If you DO already have the k9s snap installed, then
`snap refresh k9s --channel=latest/stable`